# How to check whether a directory exists or not in delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-7

I want to create a directory say `TestDir` but only when that directory does not exist. I don't find the way the check the existence of that directory.

I am using following function to create the directory.

```
CreateDir('TestDir')
```

How should I make sure that I use this `CreateDir` function only when `TestDir` does not exist?

Comment: Don't bother checking before creating. It introduces a race condition. Just call [`ForceDirectories`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.ForceDirectories) to check and create at the same time.

Comment: Rob is quite right. Just create the directory and handle any failure appropriately.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Delphi XE2, you can use the [`IOUtils`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IOUtils) unit `TDirectory` record, like this:

```
uses IOUtils;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not TDirectory.Exists('test') then
    TDirectory.CreateDirectory('test');
```

In Delphi7, you can use the DirectoryExists function from the SysUtils unit:

```
uses SysUtils, Windows;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not DirectoryExists('test') then
    CreateDir('test');
```

Answer (score 12):

There's a routine in `SysUtils` called `DirectoryExists` that should do exactly what you need...

Answer (score 3):

CreateDir can only create directories that are one level "higher" then an existing directory. E.g., CreateDir('C:\Folder1\Folder2') only works if C:\Folder1 already exists, and likewise CreateDir('C:\F1\F2\F3') only works if C:\F1\F2 exists. For creating the "in-between" folders in one step, you use Delphi's ForceDirectories.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if DirectoryExists(Edit1.Text) then
    ShowMessage(Edit1.Text + ' exists already')
  else begin
    ForceDirectories(Edit1.Text);
    if DirectoryExists(Edit1.Text) then
      ShowMessage('Folder created: ' + Edit1.Text)
    else
      ShowMessage('Could not create ' + Edit1.Text);
  end;
end;
```